# Adaptar funçao à queryselectorall

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando adaptar uma função que antes era usada apenas com QuerySelector, porém preciso que adapta-la para pegar todas as divs (QuerySelectorAll).

Vejam:

```
var draggableEl = document.querySelectorAll('[data-drag]')
```

A função

```
function move(event) {
    var el = draggableEl, magnetRect = magnet.getBoundingClientRect(), elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = this._posOrigin.x + event.pageX - this._touchOrigin.x;
    y = this._posOrigin.y + event.pageY - this._touchOrigin.y;
    moveMagnet(x + elRect.width / 2, y + elRect.height / 2);
    $('body').addClass('moving');
    var touchPos = {
        top: y,
        right: x + elRect.width,
        bottom: y + elRect.height,
        left: x
    };
    overlapping = !(touchPos.top > magnetRect.bottom || touchPos.right < magnetRect.left || touchPos.bottom < magnetRect.top || touchPos.left > magnetRect.right);
    if (overlapping) {
        var mx = magnetRect.width / 2 + magnetRect.left;
        var my = magnetRect.height / 2 + magnetRect.top;
        x = mx - elRect.width / 2;
        y = my - elRect.height / 2;
        if (!$(el).hasClass('overlap')) {
            $(el).addClass('transition');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(el).removeClass('transition');
            }, 150);

            setTimeout(function () {
                el.remove();
                setTimeout(function () {
                $('body').removeClass('moving touching');
            }, 900);
            }, 1000);
        }
        magnet.className = magnet.className.replace(' overlap', '') + ' overlap';
        el.className = el.className.replace(' overlap', '') + ' overlap';
    } else {
        if ($(el).hasClass('transition')) {
            $(el).removeClass('transition');
        }
        if ($(el).hasClass('overlap')) {
            $(el).addClass('transition');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(el).removeClass('transition');
            }, 100);
        }
        magnet.className = magnet.className.replace(' overlap', '');
        el.className = el.className.replace(' overlap', '');
    }
    moveToPos(x, y);


}
```

o que define:

```
[].forEach.call(draggableEl, function(el) {
$(el).on('touchstart mousedown', onTouchStart).on('touchmove drag', move(el)).on('touchend mouseup', onTouchEnd);
});
```

Ela me retorna:  **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** em:

```
var el = draggableEl, magnetRect = magnet.getBoundingClientRect(), elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Código completo:  jsfiddle.net/4yt1roa6

Comment: Testa mudar `var el = draggableEl` para `var el = this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando a primeira linha:

```
function move(event) {
    var el = draggableEl,
```

e sabendo que antes usavas `var draggableEl = document.querySelector('[data-drag]')` dá-me ideia que essa funcão estava a ir buscar o `draggableEl` ao escopo exterior, e funcionava porque só tinhas um único elemento. Isso não é boa prática, é melhor ter tudo dentro da funcão.

Partindo do principio que essa funcão é corrida por um event handler então o `this` será o elemento que queres e por isso podes usar:

```
function move(event){
    var el = this,
```

Para além disso esta sintaxe `.on('touchmove drag', move(el))` está incorreta. Assim vais estar a correr a funcão diretamente, deve ser somente `, move)`.

Testa assim:

```
$('[data-drag]')
    .on('touchstart mousedown', onTouchStart)
    .on('touchmove drag', move)
    .on('touchend mouseup', onTouchEnd);
```

Deste modo o jQuery vai buscar todos os elementos que tiverem uma propriedade `'[data-drag]'` e amarra-lhes oscultadores de eventos. Quando uma dessas funcões correr vai ser-lhe passado o elemento como `this` e aí podes usar como referi em cima `var el = this`.

Comment: @user3163662 podes fazer um jsFiddle com o problema?

Comment: Perdao foi erro de analise minha, era a funçao move() que nao sabia o que mover, adaptei e coloquei this na hora de chamar, desta forma `moveToPos(x,y,this)` está correto?

Comment: @user3163662: onde sugeres colocar `move(x,y,this)`? Pela a minha análize só precisas de mudar as linhas que juntei na resposta.

Comment: Veja bem, `moveToPos` foi usado para posicionar o elemento de acordo com o drag, na funçao move() ele é executado no final, porem como na funçao ele nao especificava qual dos drags movimentar ele acabava nao movimentando nada, dai surgiu minha midificaçao

Comment: @user3163662 ok, nesse caso é mais correto semãnticamente usar `move(x, y, el);`. Pois o `el` é uma referência do `this`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!